# Laravel 6 looking for tips on how to approach a problem with form switches

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-6

I started working on my first Laravel 6 web app about 2 months ago.

I've been stuck for far too long on this & I'm looking for some tips on what angle from should I look at this problem:

**Problem**
There's a form in my blade view that has a textarea for user input, 3 switches/checkboxes, a button & a disabled textarea field for the output (just a placeholder for the output at the moment).

[This is how the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAmz4.png)

The user can paste a list of domains in the textarea input field & depends on which switches/checkboxes are checked, the request (which is now an array thanks to `preg_split` in the controller) must go through all checked switches/checkboxes logic. I look at these switches like they are filters.

**Question**
Basically I'm in a never-ending search for any tips on how should I approach defining those switches. I've looked into form request validation, but that doesn't seem to be needed in solving this problem (I know I will use it later to finish up & not leave any loose ends in user inputs fields).

Now, I have a class(ListsCleaner.php) method(filters) that is called in the controller to respond to the request from the view & I think I'm moving the right way, I just don't know how to start writing each switch logic(switch1, switch2, switch3) in there:

```php
class ListsCleaner
{
    protected $domains;

    function __construct($domains)
    {
        $this->domains = $domains;
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        // Should I write all 3 switches/checkboxes logic here?
    }

}
```

My controller.php

```php
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    $domains = preg_split('/\\s/', $request->input('domains'));
    dd ($domains);
    return new ListsCleaner($domains);
}
```

dd ($domains);

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "website1.com"
  1 => ""
  2 => "website2.com"
  3 => ""
  4 => "website3.com"
]
```

My blade.php view

```xml
<form class="col s12 center-align" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('filters') }}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Switches -->
        <div class="switch col 4 valign-wrapper">
            <label>
                <input checked type="checkbox" name="Switch1" value="true">
                <span class="lever"></span>
                gTLDs
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="switch col 4 valign-wrapper">
            <label>
                <input checked type="checkbox" name="Switch2" value="true">
                <span class="lever"></span>
                Competitors
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="switch col 4 valign-wrapper">
            <label>
                <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="Switch3" value="true">
                <span class="lever"></span>
                Blogspam Sites
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 input-field">
            <textarea name="domains" id="batch_requests" class="materialize-textarea" rows="5" oninput="changedValue()"></textarea>
            <label for="batch_requests">Enter URLs separated by space or line break.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 input-field">
            <textarea disabled name="domains_cleaned" class="materialize-textarea" rows="5" oninput="changedValue()"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 left-align">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light white-text">Clean Websites</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And lastly, my full ListsCleaner class

```
namespace App\Lists;

class ListsCleaner
{
    protected $domains;

    function __construct($domains)
    {
        $this->domains = $domains;
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        // Should I write all 3 switches/checkboxes logic here?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd create three classes in `\App\Models\Filters`, and named them accordingly (class Filter1, class Filter2). Then on each class I'd have a `filter($list)` method that contains the logic.

On the controller, I'd have a property:

```
$filters = [
   'filter1' => App\Models\Filters\Filter1,
   'filter2' => App\Models\Filters\Filter2,
   'filter3' => App\Models\Filters\Filter3,
];
```

Then finally on the controller action you could loop through those and check which ones were selected by user:

```
foreach($this->filters as $filterName => $class) {
   if($request->has($filterName)) {
      $list = (new $class)->filter($list);
   }
}
```

That would allow you to run all the three (or more) filters while having their logic in a separate place, which is good for code structure.

As a bonus, you can make Filter1, Filter2 and Filter3 extend a base class `App\Models\Filters\AbstractFilter`, which would hold common data/methods these filters share.

Comment: Hi Pavel. Thanks for the answer! I've marked it as complete because at the end of the day I did go through this problem by doing something similar in my Filters by passing a constant as array & using in_array for each filter.